# Flow complaining about undefined even after type refinement

Tags: javascript, flowtype

You can view the code on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqAFgJYB2A5mALxgDeqYYAhgE5sD8AXGAIIcWWADzkArgFsARnjYA+VAF90AYzjkAzhjAYyVXiQrU6jZuza8A2gEYADABowAJgdgAzLYC6Spsz-+AwKC-VCgxchUMUnUwSjwMAGUxKQE2IQAKXSMDPUpHCgATPAAPXnFpWQBKBl9SKDB0gEIsqgA6c2q2eLE2cjBLb2ZfLowevstfZlbplsp2jlaNGFIVPHTXQpLK+0mwadbZ+bZF5dX0zeKwAGowa0rfb2VUNU1tcjwEVNpY+KSUwSwmVyjjuQA), or you can look at it here:

```
/* @flow */

type Thing = {
  arr?: Array<number>
}

const thing: Thing = {
  arr: [10, 20, 30]
}

function getSubArray(thing: Thing, index: number) {
  if (!thing.arr) return []

  return [
    ...thing.arr.slice(0, index),
    ...thing.arr.slice(index + 1)
  ]
}

const newArr = getSubArray(thing, 1)
```

I thought that doing `if (!thing.arr) return []`, would act as a "type refinement" and flow would understand that `thing.arr` was not `undefined` after that point. However, it is giving me an error saying

```
16:     ...thing.arr.slice(index + 1)           
           ^ call of method `slice`. Method cannot be called on possibly undefined value
16:     ...thing.arr.slice(index + 1)
           ^ undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you remove the second spread operation within the array literal, it type checks. I guess this first operation somehow invalidates the refinement. It is probably hard or impossible to infer types in Javascript correctly in all scenarios, because side effects can be performed literally everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Do you think the only way to get around this is to use a [type cast](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to `arr.slice` "could" mutate `thing.arr` to become `undefined`, making the second call to `slice` an error. Flow protects you from that possibility by invalidating the refinement.

You can store `thing.arr` in a `const` and use that instead (in all three locations) to avoid the potential bug.

Comment: But `slice` is a built-in and doesn't mutate anything. Shouldn't flow know built-in functions that act immutable?

Comment: See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4941 https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4458  https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3059 https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2986 https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2728 etc

Comment: Aw, that's a lot to read. All these issues boil down to _Flow can only do so much without turning into a runtime engine_.